# Cómo guardar un Checkbox de Visual Studio 2019 en MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Tengo esto en Visual Studio:

```
MySqlConnection conect = new MySqlConnection("Server = 127.0.0.1; database = QWERTY; Uid=root; pwd=12345678;");
        conect.Open();

        MySqlCommand gua = new MySqlCommand();



        gua.CommandText = ("insert into PRUEBA2 (EXITO) values ('" + cbox1.Checked + "');");


        gua.Connection = conect;
        gua.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conect.Close();
```

Y la BD en MySQL es:

```
CREATE TABLE PRUEBA2(
EXITO TINYINT
);
```

Comment: el CheckBox es un valor boleano.

Comment: Etiquetas eliminadas: CSS, VB.net. El código mostrado es C#. Por otro lado, qué estás desarrollando: Windows Forms, Console, ASP.net WebForms, ASP.net MVC?

Comment: ES C Y WEB FORMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que usas un campo de capacidad muy grande para esto, cuando podrias usar un valor bit.
Pero sobre tu lógica y base de datos actual te dejo mi respuesta.

```
 MySqlConnection conect = new MySqlConnection("Server = 127.0.0.1; database = QWERTY; Uid=root; pwd=12345678;");
        conect.Open();

        MySqlCommand gua = new MySqlCommand();

         int i = 0;

         if(cbox1.Checked)
           i =1;    

        gua.CommandText = ("insert into PRUEBA2 (EXITO) values (i);");


    gua.Connection = conect;
    gua.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conect.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrige el tipo de dato en la base de datos debe ser boolean ya que un checkbox te devuelve eso

Comment: elimina la respuesta, ya que no es la respuesta adecuada para la pregunta que hicieron.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que el lenguaje solo es C# y que es un formulario, para sacar el valor seleccionado de un `asp:checkbox` debería ser:

```
   valor =  miCheckbox.checked;
```

Por lo que tu consulta quedaría:

```
 MySqlConnection conect = new MySqlConnection("Server = 127.0.0.1; database = QWERTY; Uid=root; pwd=12345678;");
        conect.Open();
        int c = 0;
        MySqlCommand gua = new MySqlCommand();
        if(cbox1.Checked){
           c =1;
        }  
        gua.CommandText = ("insert into PRUEBA2 (EXITO) values (c);");
}

    gua.Connection = conect;
    gua.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conect.Close();
```